# .each() not working in IE

Tags: jquery-selectors

I want to get all labels inside a div, the blow piece of code works in Firefox and not working IE. Any idea. Thanks in advance.

```
<div id='discounts'>
  <label id="discount1"> discount 1</label>
  <label id="discount2"> discount 2 </label>
  <input type="text" id="discountmisc"  value="" />    
</div>

var selectLabels = {

    getLabels: function() {
        $('#discounts > label').each(function(index, item) {
            alert(index + $(item).attr('id'));
        });
    }
};

selectLabels.getLabels();
```

Comment: What JavaScript error are you getting? If any.

Comment: -1 for "not working" and not reporting `$('#discounts > label').length`

Comment: `.each()` works lazily, btw, so pst's check is not necessary.  Additionally, checking to see `if ($('#discounts > label').length > 0)` is usually slower (because people often don't cache DOM queries).  Try this on a page with jQuery on it - `$([]).each(function(){alert('hey!');});` vs `$([1]).each(function(){alert('hey!');});`

Answer (score 2):

Are you wrapped in DOM Ready functions?  i.e.

```
$(function () {
    var selectLabels = {
        getLabels: function() {
            $('#discounts > label').each(function(index, item) {
                alert(index + $(item).attr('id'));
            });
        }
    };

    selectLabels.getLabels();
});
```

or alternately:

```
var selectLabels = {
    getLabels: function() {
        $('#discounts > label').each(function(index, item) {
            alert(index + $(item).attr('id'));
        });
    }
};

$(selectLabels.getLabels);
```

or finally (because you don't care about the return value):

```
var selectLabels = {
    getLabels: function() {
        $(function () {
            $('#discounts > label').each(function(index, item) {
                alert(index + $(item).attr('id'));
            });
        });
    }
};

selectLabels.getLabels();
```

Tell me, and if so, I'll change my answer.

Comment: that's enough alternatives, eh? haha, :P